# Umbraco 7 Error Casting ASPNetCache object

Tags: umbraco7

I've been setting up a pretty vanilla website using Umbraco 7. Suddenly, I'm getting a strange error, while trying to publish an update to a page.
I don't think I've done anything to cause it. Has anybody any idea what it could be?

```
An error occured
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.Caching.AspNetCache' to type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'.
Exception Details 
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.Caching.AspNetCache' to type 'System.Collections.IEnumerable'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've received an answer over Twitter. It appears it's a Windows 10 bug, in the latest preview builds from 15002, https://our.umbraco.org/forum/using-umbraco-and-getting-started/82257-unable-to-log-into-backoffice-greeted-with-a-white-screen-log-shows-invalid-cast-exception. Apparently there is a fix which should be out in a week or so (Today's Date 01 Feb 2017)